# Как заменить фон на картинку в caja?

Tags: linux, caja

Как заменить фон на картинку в [caja](/questions/tagged/caja) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Решение с помощью dconf-editor

1. Открываем *dconf editor*   # `sudo apt-get install dconf-editor`
2. Переходим в <kbd>org > mate > caja > preferences</kbd>
3. Кликаем по *background-uri*
4. Отключаем *Use default value*
5. В *Custom value* вписываем путь до нужной картинки. К примеру :

`file:///home/username/pictures/kawaii.jpg`

Убеждаемся что *background-set* в <kbd>org > mate > caja > preferences</kbd> равен **True**.

[Результат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/751384/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%86%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%88%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%84%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2-caja)